# Chrome does not find manifest.json file in the root of public pwa folder built with Quasar

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, quasar

I have built a pwa application using the Quasar framework. It puts all the necessary files in the dist/pwa folder including a manifest.json file. 
However, Chrome's dev tools does not list this file in the sources tab. The actual web page shows up correctly in the browser. It just doesn't detect the manifest file for some reason.

I have this in the head tag of index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

This is the screenshot of the sources tab:
[image: Manifest.json is missing]

I expect the manifest.json file to show up under the sources of Chrome's dev tools and under Application it says "No Manifest Detected".

[image: No manifest detected]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was because of an error in the HTML file. I had some mismatching tags that. Just make sure your HTML file is valid and rule out the obvious first!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the manifest in the root directory from the first picture, You sure it's getting loaded? is your webapp is `(https://example.xyz)`, the manifest should be at `(https://example.xyz/manifest.json)`

and for caution use `<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">`

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is the problem. Chrome is not "finding" the manifest.json even though it's physically there. That's why it's not displaying it in the first picture. Anyway, I think this has to do with the fact that the index.html file is only briefly loaded and the router (vueroute) navigates to a different page almost immediately. I thought having manifest tag in the head of index.html would allow chrome to find it not matter which page is currently being displayed but maybe that's not true? Problem is I don't know where else to add it.

Comment: this page that is being navigated to! does it have the manifest.json? it should

Comment: It is a .vue file that is navigated to by vue's routing system. The manifest is generated by the quasar framework's build system and inserted into the index.html. So, I guess this question is really for someone who knows the in's and out's of quasar.